# Django Admin : How to update/change the image from the list_display itself without opening the change form for the entry

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

My models.py looks like

```
class User_Detail(models.Model):
    user_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users',default = 'users/profile.png')
    user_image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='user_image',
                                      processors=[ResizeToFill(75, 100)],
                                      format='JPEG',
                                      options={'quality': 60})
```

My Admin.py looks like

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('profile_pic',)

    def profile_pic(self, obj):  # receives the instance as an argument
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' %(obj._meta.app_label,  obj._meta.model_name),  args=[obj.id] )
        url_string = '<a style="margin: 2px;" href="%s">Update</a>' %(url)
        return '<img width=75 height=75 src="{thumb}" />'.format(
            thumb=obj.user_image_thumbnail.url,
        ) + url_string
    profile_pic.allow_tags = True
    profile_pic.short_description = 'User Picture'
```

I want the django administrator to update the imagefield from the admin list display itself by providing an update button next to displayed thumbnail and save it without opening the change form for the entry.
I am using the django-imagekit for generating the thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

`list_editable` is used to edit field in django admin list without going to the change form.
However, to use `list_editable` following points should be noted:

- fields in `list_editable` should also be included in `list_display`
- same field cannot be used as `link` to the change form and on `list_editable`.

Your admin.py should be:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    // "id" can be replaced by any other field to use as link
    list_display = ('id', 'profile_pic',)
    list_editable = ('profile_pic',)

    // rest of the code
```

More information on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable

Comment: profile_pic is a custom view for the list_display and list_editable doesn't seem to work for imagefield